# Why printers are not accepting IP address from DHCP

Tags: dhcp, printer

I have moved two printers from network to subnet. Since doing that the printers are not accepting assigned IP address. I can see when looking in bluecats (proteus) that the device is showing up and it has an assigned IP. However, when I look a the printer configuration I'm getting a 169.x IP address. If put the printers back on the the old network without changing any configuration it picks up it's reserved IP for that network, no problem. I can also put a laptop on the new network and it receives an IP as well.

Does anyone have any idea what might be preventing these printers from getting their assigned IP addresses?

Comment: are they wired or wifi? what's different about the subnet? what model printers?

Comment: All networks are wired

Answer (score 0):

You have an ACL around your subnet on some router/firewall and it's not letting DHCP answers back from your DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

No there’s no ACL.  Your DHCP reservations are on the old subnet scope and you need reservations in the new subnet scope, numbered in the new subnet.